# How to define alias to access enum class member through struct?

Tags: c++, enums, alias

Given the following code:

```
class A {
    enum class B {
        Member
    };
    struct C {
    };
};
```

How can I define a type alias that allows me to access `B::Member` as `C::B::Member`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct C {
    using B = A::B;
    // or: typedef A::B B;
};
```

Comment: Not OP, but would there be any difference between `using` and `typedef`?

Comment: @Frontear there is no difference